# How to Solve : 504 Gateway Timeout (Transport Exception on git remote Repository)

Tags: java, git

when i tried to send a java project to a controller of a Robot using git, i have got the following error message. Any one have an Idea what that is really means 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

"This problem is entirely due to slow IP communication between back-end computers, possibly including the Web server. Only the people who set up the network at the site which hosts the Web server can fix this problem."

Refer to the source site for possible solutions to your issue because there is no concrete fix for every 504 Gateway Timeout: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E504.html

Comment: thanks @FireWolf. I am the one who set the network. my IPs work just fine. what actully means by slow ip communication if you have any idea please!

Comment: Rebooting your router, modem or any other devices on the network may solve a 504, as they could be causing problems in the way they are connected. Make sure that, when you turn them back on, you begin with the modem, router, and then any devices between that and your computer.
Some issued with DNS servers can cause 504 errors, so it may be worth changing to a different DNS server. These are assigned to you by your ISP, who may be able to help you if you are not sure what to do.